# How to fetch record with secondary key in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have searched for solutions but can't find any that addresses this perfectly.
I have two models like below

```
class Payments extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'payments';

    public function investment_()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Investments', 'investment_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

and

```
class Investments extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'investments';

    public function payments_()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Payments', 'investment_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Payments has an amount column while investment also has an amount column.

How can I fetch all payments only on the condition that the total payments for a particular investment is at least half of the investment amount?

I don't know how to structure the query so that the payments can pick their corresponding investment_values and check the condition.

This is what i have so far in my controller 
`$payments = Payments::where('amount', '>=', Investment::where('id', Payments::where(?)))->get();`

Note: I don't know what to put in the question mark or to know if my approach is correct.

Here is a sample wrong query that illustrates it better

`SELECT a.SUM(a.amount) AS amount FROM payments as a, investments as b where a.investment_id = b.id and a.sum(a.amount)*2 = b.amount GROUP BY a.investment_id;`

Comment: with eloquent you can't do it without touching PHP, instead with query builder you can do it all in the  Database side

Answer (score 0):

The query is just

```
SELECT a.SUM(a.amount) AS amount 
FROM payments as a JOIN investments as b 
     ON a.investment_id = b.id 
GROUP BY a.investment_id
HAVING SUM(a.amount)*2 < b.amount;
```

You can easily translate thin in a Laravel Query builder element, but if you just need this, you can use `DB::select('query')` to get them

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solves your problem. Please check. Thanks

```
\App\Payment::where(function ($query) {
            $query->whereRaw('(select SUM(payment_amount) from payments as payments_final where investment_id = payments.investment_id) >= (select investment_amount/2 from investments where id=payments.investment_id)');
        })
        ->get();
```